# How to connect database Oracle TNS information using R2DBC with Spring Reactive?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc

I'm trying to connect oracle database in my spring project using reactive. I need the reactive database connectivity with Oracle TNS specifications.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to follow by Spring documentation ?

https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc

Read here about TNS:

https://github.com/oracle/oracle-r2dbc

Answer (score 0):

just add this dependancies and then connect like the old way this works fine with me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
    <version>19.11.0.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>oraclepki</artifactId>
    <version>21.5.0.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>osdt_cert</artifactId>
    <version>21.5.0.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>osdt_core</artifactId>
    <version>21.5.0.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

```
spring.datasource.configuration.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//IP:PORT/SID
spring.datasource.configuration.username=USER
spring.datasource.configuration.password=PASSWORD
spring.datasource.configuration.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

thanks to [SombrHack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18336050/sombrhack) for this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72418303/7241713)